# Using htmlagilitypack how can we determine whether URL or required webpage is loaded or not

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I want to know that, using `htmlagilitypack` how can we determine whether webpage of given URL is loaded or not, because I want to associate this load with the process bar. Is there any idea how can to do that ?

I also want to perform some functions after load of webpage. Is there any method like webbrowser control have state WebBrowserReadyState.Complete ?

For example, I have a code for web browser control

```
    While Not WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        If timerCouunt = True Then Exit While
        Application.DoEvents()
        If ProgressBar1.Value >= 100 Then ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 20
    End While
```

How can I do the above using `htmlagilitypack` ?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack has an HtmlWeb utility class that can download a page, but its synchronous, unlike the webbrowser.

Alternatively you can use HttpWebRequest or WebClient to download the page text and Html Agility Pack to parse it. Both can use asynchronous methods, for example the WebClient has the [DownloadDataCompleted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted.aspx).